# JS Link not working for Calculated Column with OpenPopUpPage command (SPO)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, jslink

I am trying to make a JS Link for a calculated column that creates a button that invokes a modal pop form. The Calculated column has the Internal Name 'btnEditor', external name 'Update'.

**Questions**

- What is wrong with my script? I got **ctx is undefined**
- What text should remain in the calculated column 'Update' once I upload the JS Link?

**THE COMPONENTS**

1. *txtId*: Text column populated with the Item ID
2. *edit-file.png*: The icon from my images folder
3. *ClassifyForm.aspx*: The custom edit form that is invoked on 'onClick'

**Here is the Calculated Column...**

```
    ="<div><a href='#' onclick="&"SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage('https://pizzabeach.sharepoint.com/SourcesLibrary/Forms/ClassifyForm.aspx?ID="&txtId&"');"&">"&"<img src='/SiteAssets/elements/images/edit-file.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;' title='Click this icon to Edit this item'>"&"</a></div>"
```

**Here is the JS Link script...**

```
(function () {

var requestCtx = {};
requestCtx.Templates = {};

requestCtx.Templates.Fields = {
'btnEditor': {'Update': linkFieldTemplate}     
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(requestCtx);

})();

function linkFieldTemplate(ctx) {
var title = ctx.CurrentItem["txtId"];

return "<a href='" + title + "'><img src='/SiteAssets/elements/images/edit-
file.png' style='height:20px;width:20px;'></a>");
}
```

Comment: Which is the error?

Comment: ctx is undefined -- is this because of the text in my calculated column? should the original formula be in there or something entirely different?